# calling javascript function inside html

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>    
            var myFunction = function(){
                return "hello world";
            }
        </script>    
        myFunction();        
    </body>
</html>
```

I just finished the code academy course on javascript but it didn't taught me how to code javascript inside html. I need to display hello world inside the html's  tag using the function is this possible? my friend told me I need jquery just to do this.

Comment: wrap it in `<script>` tag

Comment: use `document.write` to write inside HTML in place of return

Answer (score 2):

You have to specifically tell the webpage to execute your function when it's loaded.

Instead of returning the string I believe you'd like to write it in the body of the webpage.

This is a simple way to do so :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var myFunction = function(){
                document.body.innerHTML = "hello world";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='myFunction();'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Also script tags must be contained in head tag."_ That's simply not true.

Comment: However, credits where due, this is one of the few answers that adds the returned value to the HTML without the awful `document.write`.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've removed the script in head tag sentence.

Comment: Excellent :-) Now this is a decent answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<Script>

function myFunction(){
    document.write("hello");
}


</script>
<Script>
    myFunction();
    </Script>

</body>
</html>
```

This was asked already
[How to call a javascript function within an HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869639/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-within-an-html-body)

I just replace the

tag with document.write

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. It's unpredictable.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload='myFunction()'>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myFunction = function(){
       return "hello world";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```