# My button for a script doesn't work and only shows the code

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am using html to try to create an calculator
I am using HTML for the buttons to run javascript.

```
<form method="get" action="a.js">
    <button  onclick="a.js">addition</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it shouldn't :)

Comment: May you make sure the example is a [mcve]? Otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: You have to import your script, then call the function, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869639/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-within-an-html-body/19869671)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example to get you started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Button Click</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="get" action="a.js">
      <button onclick="handleClick()">addition</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleClick() {
        console.log("clicked.");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
function handleClick() {
  console.log("clicked.");
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="a.js">
  <button onclick="handleClick()">addition</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, when you click the submit button, it opens the `a.js` file instead of doing what you want.

If you want to send a request (as you provided a form), you need a server to process the data.

In your case, you may want to :

1- Import your script with the `script` tag

2- Replace your form attribute with `action="#"`

3- Call the function with `onclick='myFunction()` in your button tag (`onclick` lowercase according to w3schools)

Comment: so instead of <form></form> I do <script></script> ? Also can you clarify on how to make the  function javasscript? Sorry I'm new to coding